# PHP для чтения com порта?

Tags: php

Для роботы с *COM портом* есть специальный класс: `php_serial.class.php`,

```
<?php

include "php_serial.class.php";

// Let's start the class
$serial = new phpSerial;

// First we must specify the device. This works on both linux and windows (if
// your linux serial device is /dev/ttyS0 for COM1, etc)
$serial->deviceSet("COM3");

// Then we need to open it
$serial->deviceOpen();

// To write into
$serial->sendMessage("m");

// If you want to change the configuration, the device must be closed
$serial->deviceClose();

?>
```

Это зажигает светодиод `RX` при каждом обновлении страницы
но как просто вывести данные, которые пришли в ком порт?

Answer (score 1):

Вывод полного пакета

```
echo $serial->readPort();
```

Вывод по байтам

```
while (true) {
    echo $serial->readPort(1);
}
```

Comment: Просто <?php include class а дальше эти строки и все?

Comment: Это после `$serial->deviceOpen();` напишите, и должно работать. А логику сами решайте

Comment: Спасибо за помощь